# Send email through SMTP using a non Gmail Account in Firebase

Tags: email, firebase, smtp, google-cloud-functions

Is possible send emails from a non Gmail SMTP email account in firebase cloud functions?

I couldn't find this info.

Comment: In log I have no errors. Instead, I have OK status. However the message never arrives.

RESP: 465 { accepted: [ 'mxxxio@crexxxxor.com' ],
  rejected: [],
  response: '250 OK id=1dfssnZ-00XDxxx-2Z',
  envelope: { from: 'oxxxe@xxxxc.com', to: [ 'mxxxio@crexxxxor.com' ] },
  messageId: '<2ca227a6-ec-97-c01a-053550f5fddb@ oxxxe.com>' }

Comment: Yes, it is possible to send email from Cloud Functions with a different provider. If you're having trouble making this work, share the [minimal code that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen
Here are the code: https://gist.github.com/nanocreaator/53e6a1a616fbf0bdb1df616f9af9050e
The answer I have in function console after execute is the same as I already mentioned before your answer (250 OK). However, the email never arrives.
Thanks

Comment: Node and Firebase has a weird issue with TLS. You need to configure your transport like this:
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.example.com',
  secureConnection: true,
  port: 465,
  auth: {
     user: 'emailaddress',
     pass: 'password'
  },
  tls:{
      secureProtocol: "TLSv1_method"
  }
});

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable billing on your Firebase project. As per the documentation, "this is required to send requests to non-Google services". More details here --> https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users#functions-code

Comment: Yes! I already did and when I sent using a gmail account it works perfectly. However, with a non-Gmail SMTP configuration do not work and no errors were displayed.